# Would like to concatenate list of fields one of which is a URL link

Tags: php

```
$list[] = '<li><a href="' . $row->tr_survey_link . '"> ' . $row->Survey_Subject . '</a></li>';
```

How would I add a field after the Href each time I try I get nothing showing in list...

want to add $row->Evaluator_Type before or after link.... but it just does not seem to work

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Is the variable `$row` an object or array?  If it is an array, you will need to use the syntax `$row['variable_name']`

Comment: $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM tr_survey_list WHERE email=" . $db->Quote($email));
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
$list = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $list[] = '<li><a href="' . $row->tr_survey_link . '"> ' . $row->Survey_Subject . '</a></li>';
}
return '<ol>' . implode($list) . '</ol>';

Comment: I tried this . ' ' . $row->Evaluator_Type

Comment: You need to provide more context: what are the possible values that 'Evaluator_Type' can have, and under what contexts would they appear before or after the link? Does the contents of 'tr_survey_link' show up as you'd expect?

Comment: Yes it shows... the link correctly with the link text... what I would like to do is show the link and its text with another field with a space before it  so there should be two columns for each line...

Answer (score 0):

print_r($row); and check the outputs to see if you are using correct variable names.

Try assigning to $list[0] instead of $list[]

Update:

```
 $list[] = '<li><a href="' . $row->tr_survey_link . '"> ' . $row->Survey_Subject . '</a> ' .  $row->Evaluator_Type . '</li>';
```

Let us know if above does not work.

Comment: Using correct field names... I have tested it without the href... url link and it displayed... just seems to disappear when I try to add field before after <a  <a/>

Comment: The code I showed works... I just want to add another field or two in the list command...

Comment: Then use _array_push($list, "field 1", "field 2");_

Comment: Okay but how do you do a href for one of the field names... that is what I am wrestling with

Comment: I am not sure i quite understand your problem but i updated my answer, let me know if it works or not.

Comment: This question Answer thing does not display well... what did you update?

Comment: $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM tr_survey_list WHERE email=" . $db->Quote($email));
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
$list = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $list[] = '<li><a href="' . $row->tr_survey_link . '"> ' . $row->Survey_Subject . '</a></li>';
}
return '<ol>' . implode($list) . '</ol>';

Comment: The code above works fine for me.... gives me the link with the name of the link instead of the full URL... which is what I want  but I would like to add a field or two after or before in this statement - $list[] = '<li><a href="' . $row->tr_survey_link . '"> ' . $row->Survey_Subject . '</a></li>';

Comment: I just can not see how to format the $row->new_field before or after the url and text name in the above line of code

Comment: Your solution just added the self to the end of the URL... I just wanted to display it with a space after the URL

Comment: Ok one last update to the answer, i hope this is the solution or i give up

Comment: This is the end result I want: 
1. Survey Subject Name 1 (with link to URL embedded )  Evaluator Type 
2. Survey Subject Name 2 (with link to URL embedded )  Evaluator Type
...

Comment: That worked to a degree thanks!  Although the URL link was destroyed

Comment: then remove urlencode from the href, but urlencode assures that the output is safe to be used in a url. but if it breaks, you can remove it only use $row->tr_survey_link

Comment: this is what worked... thank you so much... was banging my head against the Desk!

$list[] = '<li><a href="' . $row->tr_survey_link . '"> ' . $row->Survey_Subject . '</a> ' .  $row->Evaluator_Type . '</li>';